# Manage two Oculus Quest 2

Tags: meta-quest-2

We had gotten a 64GB Oculus Quest 2 over a year ago. I bought a manufacturer-refurbished 256GB one for a good deal the other day.

We may keep them both or might sell the 64GB Quest - depending on how much we use them.

How can a set them up so that they can share games? I've read that you can set it up so that games can be shared between Quest A and Quest B but then you can't share from Quest B to Quest A.

I would like the 256 GB quest to be the main one since any new games would be added to that one. I do have several games on the 64GB Quest that I would like to use on the 256GB one.

I haven't got the second one yet and only started to set up a Meta account so I can get the referral bonus.

How should I set them up to make the 256GB the main one and share games with the 64GB one (and any other benefits to having 2)?

Comment: Using the same account on both will allow the games to be shared between them.

Comment: @clbx  Duh - I didn't think that was an option. For some reason, I thought I needed a separate account for each. Could I still get the referral though?

Comment: I'm not sure about the referral. Maybe you could create a new account on the headset to get the referral and then switch it to the other one?